# Workflow Rule to update a text field

Tags: workflow, formula

I am trying to create a workflow rule for a field update when the Lead Owner is changed from a Queue to a user only when the Queue owner = certain queues.
Here is what I have so far:

```
AND(
ISCHANGED(Owner_Name__c), 
(PRIORVALUE(Owner_Name__c) = 'Queue - Inform') OR
(PRIORVALUE(Owner_Name__c) = 'Queue - Qualifa') OR
(PRIORVALUE(Owner_Name__c) = 'Queue - Televerde') OR
(PRIORVALUE(Owner_Name__c) = 'Queue - Market One'))
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: It's the Syntax Errors i keep receiving. First its:    Missing ')'

Comment: Try replacing OR with `||`

Comment: I tried that as well AND(
ISCHANGED(Owner_Name__c), 
(PRIORVALUE(Owner_Name__c) = 'Queue - Inform') ||
(PRIORVALUE(Owner_Name__c) = 'Queue - Qualifa') ||
(PRIORVALUE(Owner_Name__c) = 'Queue - Televerde') ||
(PRIORVALUE(Owner_Name__c) = 'Queue - Market One'))                        Error: Formula result is data type (Boolean), incompatible with expected data type (Text).

Comment: See @Adrian's post below.... that's what I would've done, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not how `OR` syntax works. You pass it a bunch of clauses and if any of them are true, it returns true (e.g. `OR(condition1, condition2)`). It's just like `AND` (notice you already use `AND(condition1, condition2)`). So your formula should be:

```
AND(
    ISCHANGED(Owner_Name__c),
    OR(
        (PRIORVALUE(Owner_Name__c) = 'Queue - Inform'),
        (PRIORVALUE(Owner_Name__c) = 'Queue - Qualifa'),
        (PRIORVALUE(Owner_Name__c) = 'Queue - Televerde'),
        (PRIORVALUE(Owner_Name__c) = 'Queue - Market One')
    )
)
```

Comment: You JUST beat me to it (see my comment above). Upvoted.

Comment: thanks I changed it to that and got this error: Error: Formula result is data type (Boolean), incompatible with expected data type (Text).

Comment: @ShelleyHolloway You're using this formula in your evaluation of whether or not to fire the WFR?

Comment: The rule criteria is set to TRUE and I'm using it  on action to for field update

Comment: @ShelleyHolloway You should use the above as your criteria instead of `TRUE`.